# Memory access violation when using Boost::Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to do serializations using Boost's serialization library, but they always fail with the same unhelpful runtime error. Say, for example, I have a simple struct:

```
struct test {
    unsigned int value;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int const version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(value);
    }
};
```

This compiles fine. Then I'm doing a round trip of saving object of the `test` type to archive and loading it back again.

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_serialization)
{
    test a{42};

    stringstream ss;
    text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
}

// ... lots of other tests that pass fine
```

This also compiles fine. However, I get the following error when running the suite.

```
Entering test case "test_serialization"
unknown location(0): fatal error in "test_serialization": memory access violation at address: 0x00000038: no mapping at fault address
Test is aborted
```

All other tests except those involving serialization run as expected.

What could cause the problem?

---

My settings:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
boost 1.57 / boost 1.58
clang 3.4 / gcc 4.8.2
```

Building with `-lboost_serialization -lboost_unit_test_framework`.

Comment: sounds like [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to me. Are you sure you (re)compiled (everything) against the versions of the runtime libraries you are actually using?

Comment: The provided code works without exceptions. See it [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135f5c0c3a35029a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had multiple boost installations, boost headers included were from version 1.57/1.58, while the `libboost_serialization.so` library was from version 1.54.

I recompiled with `-L/actual/latest/boost/lib/path -lboost_serialization -lboost_unit_test_framework`, and it worked.